# Easy Leetcode question, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

Tags: python, roman-numerals

I'm beginner in coding and I am working on some easy leetcode questions along the way. The question is converting roman numerals to integers and when I run this code, it says the "string index out of range". Rather than looking for other answers, I wanted to understand what I did wrong. I appreciate the help!

```
s = "CCXLVII"

roman_dict = {
    'C' : 100,
    'L' : 50,
    'X' : 10,
    "V" : 5,
    "I" : 1
}

temp = 0

for i in range(len(s)):
    if roman_dict[s[i]] > roman_dict[s[i+1]] and i + 1 < len(s): #string index out of range
        temp = temp - roman_dict[s[i]]
    else:
        temp = temp + roman_dict[s[i]]
```

Comment: You are looping over length of `s`. So when `i` becomes `len(s) - 1`, `s[i+1]` will cause that error. You need to move `i + 1 < len(s)` at the front of the `if` condition

Comment: Also, unrelated to your question. I think `roman_dict[s[i]] > roman_dict[s[i+1]]` should be `roman_dict[s[i]] < roman_dict[s[i+1]]`

Comment: Oh thank you I didn't catch that part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to swap the order of the conditionals:

Change:

```
if roman_dict[s[i]] > roman_dict[s[i+1]] and i + 1 < len(s):
```

To:

```
if i + 1 < len(s) and roman_dict[s[i]] > roman_dict[s[i+1]]:
```

This makes it so that the boundary check is done before attempting to access the `i+1` index. Python will [short-circuit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) the condition as soon as `i + 1 >= len(s)` is *true*